# Is it safe to ssh to a compromised server?

Tags: ssh, file-sharing

I have a compromised server, I want to know if I ssh to that , then the malware can also compromise my local machine (transfer a file to it and ...) or not?

Comment: Generally-speaking, no. But there have been ssh client vulnerabilities in the past. You'd need to see if your client is vulnerable. That said, this is not a question you should be asking: shut the server down and never put it on the network again.